Low Quiescent Current over USB Type-C
I'm working on a battery powered project which I'm currently planning on powering over USB Type-C for flexibility. The 5V/3A spec would satisfy my needs for the high end of power draw, however, I want to have the ability to sleep my device in a very low \$I_Q\$ state while being plugged in over Type-C. I would use a 21700 cell or similar into a boost converter (e.g. TPS61235) to supply power, and that chip only draws ~10 µA under light load. I would like to keep my idle power under 100 µA if possible.
Now, the issue I'm facing, is that even with nothing connected, the cable attach mechanism (Rp/Rd) of Type-C requires ~330 µA flowing at all times, whether using resistors or a current source. Is there any way to get around this? Additionally, is there a way I would be able to implement DRP on my battery supply so I can charge it over the same port (e.g. using something like a TUSB320LI but keeping it mostly in shutdown with some clever trick)

Which part are you designing? A device powered/charged over USB-C, or a host with ability of sourcing 5V3A? Or a power bank with 21700 cell and 5V3A output?
